# projectin in a new range area using biomod2

Tags: r, biomod2

I have a list of alien species and by using their native range, I want to predict for the Mediterranean using `MaxEnt` models which will calibrated with data about the native distribution of these species, with the true occurrences in the Mediterranean Sea. All the analyses were conducted in `R` using the `biomod2` package.

Comment: can you add the code you're using to your question and show the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Did you read this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/sdm.pdf), explaining how `MaxEnt` models work in `R`, and giving step-by-step examples of how to do it yourself?

Comment: I work on the modeling niche Lessepsian species I have a little problem I can not seem to find how models could from the native data ranks give me a projection in the Mediterranean potential distributions that I could then compare it with the actual repairs in the Mediterranean I tried several script with this one and it turned out that it does not give the result I was waiting